# Share Memory in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

Is it safe to use `shm_unlink` even there are other process currently open the shared memory?

For exmaple:

Process B `shm_open` and then Process A `shm_unlink`. Is it ok for Process B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to call shm_unlink if another process has it opened.  Per the man page for shm_unlink:

> The operation of shm_unlink() is analogous to unlink(2): it removes a
> shared memory object name, and, once all processes have unmapped the
> object, de-allocates and destroys the contents of the associated
> memory region. After a successful shm_unlink(), attempts to shm_open()
> an object with the same name will fail (unless O_CREAT was specified,
> in which case a new, distinct object is created).